# How to add curve with mean values per category to plot

Tags: r

I have two variables: `Std.gesamt` (a total of hours worked) and `alter` (age, a factor with 11 age categories).

I have ploted the distribution of hours worked in each age category and would like to add a curve that shows the mean value in each age category.

I have tried this, but it adds a vertical line in my last age category:

```
plot(as.factor(B$alter), B$Std.gesamt, main ="Gesamtstunden in B (Apr16 - Apr17)")
abline(v=mean(B$Std.gesamt),col="blue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot this using `ggplot2` package (`geom_smooth` adds "Smoothed conditional means")

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(B, aes(factor(alter), Std.gesamt)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    geom_smooth(aes(group = 1)) +
    ggtitle("Gesamtstunden in B (Apr16 - Apr17)")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! What does the element `group = 1` stand for?

Comment: `B$alter` is numeric, but you transform it into factor (with `factor()`) because you want to plot boxplots. This turns your numeric x-axis into categorical. `group = 1` uses brute force to plot numeric smooth onto categorical axis.

Comment: @Hanna if my answer helped to solve your problem you can accept it.

Comment: One extension: I want to draw these plots for different divisions (B is one of them). How could I merge those different plots into one graphic?

Comment: @Hanna Can't tell without looking into your data, but I guess that you have to merge your data.frames and use `facet_grid` from `ggplot2`